# Want to create a java script array after click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Want to create a JavaScript array, after click event.
This is my function:

```
$(function() {

     $('#tree,#tree-combined').on('acitree', function(event, api, item, eventName, options) {
         if (api.isItem(item)) {
             var itemSelect= [];
             itemSelect.push(api.getId(item));
             var itemEvent= eventName;
             if (event) {
                 if (itemEvent=="checked") {
                     var a = api.getId(item);
                     eval('var arrayTmp = ' + a); 
                     document.getElementById("Name").value = arrayTmp;
                 }
             }
         } else {
             var itemEvent1= eventName;
         }
     });
});
```

And I want to use this array as hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="Name[]" name="Name[]" />
```

Comment: Create a fiddle and please mention the problems which you are facing.

Comment: user json stringify and then add it into hidden field

Comment: Please give me an example related to my proble that how would i use json stringyfy. Thanks